How to remove cached raspberry pi desktop image from Ubuntu?
I installed the raspberry pi imager app from the official repositories in my computer running Ubuntu 24.04, and used it to flash a Raspberry Pi image to an SD card. However, now the image is cached (I verified it is true, because now I can flash without downloading).
Where is this image stored? I want to remove it to recover some disk storage.


Delete the file $HOME/.cache/Raspberry\ Pi/Imager/lastdownload.cache.
